# How to ignore the EIdConnClosedGracefully when using Indy on Delphi?

Tags: delphi, get, indy, digest-authentication, idhttp

I'm making a GET request with Digest auth, but it excepts on the `HTTP.Get`.

```
HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
try
  HTTP.OnAuthorization := HTTPAuthorization;
  HTTP.Request.Clear;
  HTTP.HTTPOptions := HTTP.HTTPOptions + [hoInProcessAuth];

  Memo1.Text := HTTP.Get(LabeledEdit1.Text);
  ShowMessage('GOT!!!');
finally
  HTTP.Free;
end;
```

The exception is a EIdConnClosedGracefully.

`HTTP.Response.ResponseCode` is 401
`HTTP.Response.ResponseText` is 'Connection Closed Gracefully.'

How can I get the response body even with this exception?

Comment: `EIdConnClosedGracefully` means the server closed the connection while Indy was still performing socket I/O on it. In that case, you can't rely on the `TIdHTTP.Response` being meaningful, since the response wasn't fully read. But I find it very odd that the `ResponseText` is being set to `'Connection Closed Gracefully'` for a 401 response. It shouldn't be. It is usually set to `'Unauthorized'` or similar instead. `TIdHTTP` doesn't set the `ResponseText` to the text of a raised exception, it is set to whatever the server sends in the 1st line of the response.

Comment: `TIdHTTP` automatically handles 401 responses when `hoInProcessAuth` is enabled. The calling code should be seeing an `EIdHTTPProtocolException` for any HTTP error, including 401, but not until the number of authentication attempts (`TIdHTTP.AuthRetries`) exceeds the maximum number of attempts allowed (`TIdHTTP.MaxAuthRetries`), which would indicate that authentication is failing too many times to continue. It is kind of hard to diagnose the problem at hand without seeing the *actual* error that is being reported, and whether it is occurring at the HTTP level or the TCP level.